# No alternative keyboard layouts in XFCE

Tags: keyboard-layout, xfce

**Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS with XFCE 4.12**

When I go to Settings->Keyboard->Layout in XFCE I cannot change the keyboard model as US is the only one available.

I'm sure this was okay before I installed xfce.

How do I make the other layouts available? I'm in the UK.

Comment: It's beginning to look like an XRDP problem. I'll report back with findings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is an XRDP issue.

You'll need to create the right keymap while working on a non-xrdp session.
Useful links, which include instructions for generating and editing keymaps, as well as some ready made keymaps are below.

For UK people, I'm using [this 0809 keymap](http://c-nergy.be/downloads/km-0809_v1.1.ini)

http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=3858

http://component-parts.blogspot.co.uk/2012/08/fixing-uk-keyboard-mapping-for-xrdp.html

[country keycodes](http://xrdp.sourceforge.net/documents/keymap/rfc1766.html)